# Strange User Crash Report: Null Pointer exception for something that is definitely there

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, google-play

So my [little app is available on Google "Play"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epublica.android.kidsmusicplayerfree) and got a few downloads so far. Now the developer console reported a crash.

This crash report is weird.

First of all, the developer console is giving me a stack trace and the reason for the crash, a null pointer exception. But there is no information on the Android version or the hardware, so I cannot create an emulator setup to recreate the bug.

Here's the offending line:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.speechbubble)).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.welcome_nomusic));
```

On all devices and emulators I tested, this works and results in a nice [speech bubble message](https://lh5.ggpht.com/tbkV7zOw1k7o5HFS4ZFU7SZcUmvmc4T72JOffXNYDSKW56AdChrS-x6ZDLXEuRfL_DQ).

And why should it not work? I *know* that the layout contains a view called "speechbubble" and that the string resources contain a text message for "welcome_nomusic".

So, any idea what is going on here and how to fix it?

---

**Fixed, thanks for the answers.** My mistake was adding additional layouts for different screen resolutions and not testing all of them after my last code change. :-/

Comment: Can you put the complete trace of the error? 

Do you have  a different layout for the different sizes? (xdpi xlarge ... )

Comment: Aaaargh. I guess that was it. Yes, indeed, there are different layouts and I didn't update all of them. Now where is a table I can bite?

Comment: Yes, the different layouts were the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Uploaded the fixed version now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What may be happening is the Resource you are trying to call may not be present for a certain device or it is struggling to find it.

Check all the layouts/strings/resources are the same across different sizes etc. The new Lint tools in ADT 17 + should help

Comment: Thanks. The different layouts were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just log every object involved:

```
log("R: " + R);
log("R.id: " + R.id);
log("R.id.speechbubble: " + R.id.speechbubble);
log("textView: " + findViewById(R.id.speechbubble));
log("getResources(): " + getResources());
log("R.string: " + R.string);
log("R.string.welcome_nomusic: " + R.string.welcome_nomusic);
log("text: " + getResources().getString(R.string.welcome_nomusic));
```

Somewhere in this block you will have a null.